# I was wondering whether my structure is fine for the application i made

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, express, spring-boot

Basically, i used react.js for the front end and node.js/express.js as backend to be able to store and access data from my database(mySQL). I also used JAVA springboot to create my own api to fetch data from external sources such as JIRA with basic authentication. I was wondering if this is a good ‘structure’ in order to fetch data from jira, display it in a table and store it in my database. Now my other queston is, i run 3 local host servers to make this function, if i want to deploy and put all this in a web server would it make me need 3 servers running ? I’ve never deployed  anything so my main concern is that. Thank you

Comment: I think docker https://www.docker.com/ is what you need do run your services. The role of java for authentication is not clear to me. Can you explain more, please?

Comment: Basically, I used JAVA springboot to fetch data from a URL endpoint, i dont know if its a bad thing if i want to run my services. Im using 2 back-end frameworks mainly speaking, node.js/express.js and java springboot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can put things simple and easy for you by choosing **one** **language/framework** for all your back-end process. Between **NodeJs/Express** and **Java/Spring** you can choose what you really like and are more comfortable with. Because definitely what you can do with one you can almost do it with the other. It is just a question of choice if there is no requirement.

About the second question, do you mean 3 physical servers ? It is possible to run all your three apps on the same physical server. You just have to set a specific port for each one.

Comment: Ohhh i see, so I did something bad then? I used 2 frameworks for back-end

Comment: Yeah, because let's say im running the **java spring boot** server locally to **localhost:8080/jsondata**, then in **node.js / express.js** **localhost:2000/getData** , then in react.js i use **localhost:3000/**

Comment: So is it okay then if I use java spring boot and node.js/express.js as the back-end?

Comment: What you can do with java Spring boot you can do it with node.js/Express too. So the best case will be to use either Spring or Express. Not both at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using express / node for my back-end xd